# Xamarin forms refresh carouselview after dowloading data

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I am learning xamarin,

I am trying to refresh my carouselView every time I download data.

The data are downloaded correctly, but the problem is when I download new data and I want to swap on my carrouselView to see my new data after a previous data download.

The carousel 'move' and positionning me at my previous position (index) even if I want to be position on position (index) 0 at every data download

How can I refresh correctly my carouselview ?

Here is my code cs:

```
try
        {

        // trying to refresh by renitializing my carouselView
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            NewsList.Position = 0;
            NewsList.ItemsSource = null;
          
           
        });

            
        // Perform the Web request and get the response
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;

        // Data Downloaded
        string json = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(json);
        JArray MyJsonResult = (JArray)joResponse["value"];



          List<NewsModel> newsObj = new List<NewsModel>();
             
                foreach (var j in MyJsonResult)
            {

                    joResponse2 = JObject.Parse(j.ToString());

                    if (joResponse2["image"]!= null)
                    {
                        

                        var news = new NewsModel();
                        news.NewsName = GetFewWordsSentence(joResponse2["name"].ToString()) ;
                        news.NewsDate = joResponse2["datePublished"].ToString();
                        news.NewsImageUrl = joResponse2["image"]["contentUrl"].ToString(); 
                        newsObj.Add(news);

                     // feed my carouselView in the loop for performance
                       // I have already try, to put this line out of the loop but it is not refresh correctly also
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        NewsList.ItemsSource = newsObj;

                   });


                }
               
                }

                    
    }


    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", e.Message);

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The carousel 'move' and positionning me at my previous position (index) even if I want to be position on position (index) 0 at every data download

According to your description, you download data and display CarouselView, then you swap item for CarouselView in any position. You want to display new data and go to position 0 when download data again, am I right?

If yes, I suggest you can use observablecollection to replace List firstly, it implement INotifyPropertychanged interface to notify when data update.

```
  public ObservableCollection<NewsModel> newsObj { get; set; }
```

then clear data when you download data again,

```
 newsObj.Clear();
```

Using ScrollTo scrolls the item at the specified index into view.

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>
        {
            newsList.ScrollTo(0);
        }
        ) ;
```

Comment: Hi, It is not working. I have the same probleme. THe carouselView is scrolling well to index 0  but once I touch it,  it moves at to the previous position

Comment: @hugo This is my sample that you can take a look:https://github.com/CherryBu/carouselview, I don't have your problem.

Comment: I was hoping to study your code, Cherry.  The link does not work though.

Comment: The carouselView not only "jumps" to previous position, I also get System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException if new number of items less then last carouselView position.